# Add a vector at the end of another

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a method to add a vector at the end of another vector? For example if my vectors are

```
std::vector<int> v1(3);
std::vector<int> v2(3);

/* ... initialize vectors ... */
/* ... for example, v1 is 1 2 3 and v2 is 4 5 6 ... */
```

which is the smartest way to add `v2` at the end of `v1` (i.e. to obtain `v1` = 1 2 3 4 5 6) without using a cycle and a `push_back`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `insert`:

```
vec1.insert(vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
```

This will add all the elements in the range [`vec2.begin()`, `vec2.end()`) (that is, all the elements in `vec2`) to `vec1`, starting at position `vec1.end()` (that is, right after all the elements of `vec1`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I remember when I first learned about iterators... it was amazing. I'm still impressed by the flexibility of the system.

Comment: And if I want to add to v1 the second and third element of v1 what I have to do? (ie I want as result v1 = 1 2 3 2 3)

Comment: @Wellen You'd have to manually insert the elements one at a time. You might want to look up a tutorial on containers, iterators, and algorithms for examples of how to do this.

Comment: these are bad news... there isn't a method that return the iterator to the 'i' element?